# Is that true that $\{0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28 \}$ is NOT a subring of ring $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is that true that $\{0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28 \}$ is NOT a subring of ring $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$? I know that it is a subgroup of order $8$. I know that it is in fact a ring (it's closed and commutative under multiplication mod $32$), but it has not a neutral element of multiplication mod $32$, that is $1$. Is that correct?

Comment: That depends on your definition of ring. Some authors do not require unity, in which case this **is** a subring. If, on the other hand, you require rings to have unity, then subrings have to have unity and, thus, this is **not** a subring.

Comment: More on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Multiplicative_identity_and_the_term_%22ring%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not its not a subring since the unit element is missing.

But it is an ideal (all multiples of $4$) of $\Bbb Z_{32}$.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. Thank you sir, I will accept this answer in 10min.

Comment: By the way you define subring, $(2\Bbb{Z}, +, \cdot) $ is not a subring of $\Bbb{Z}$. So, Ring with unity and ring are same. Good, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Although $\{0,4,8,...,28\}\bmod 32$ lacks a unit element and thus is not a subring of $\mathbb Z/32\mathbb Z$, certain other moduli do admit arithmetic progressions where some element other than $1$ takes the place of unity. An example is $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ in $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$. Although $1$ is absent, the element $6$ is easily verified to satisfy $6a\equiv (a)(6)\equiv a\bmod 10$ for all elements in the set. We even have all nonzero elements with multiplicative inverses that give a product $\equiv6\bmod10$ ($2×8,4×4,6×6$). Thus we have all the properties necessary for both a ring and a field if we render the unit element properly.

In general, $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ will contain such subrings whenever $n$ is squarefree, like $10$ but unlike $32$.